# AppStore submission using non English main language

Tags: localization, app-store

I use French as my main language for submission on the AppStore.
I used to add English as a second language but I discovered that many stores with their own language (Germany, Italy, Spain, China, and so on) don't use my English localization but my French main language to display my apps !
Do I need to add English localization in all available languages ? It's a bit painful and a lot of work to do.
I could make my main language as English but French is not listed in the other localization languages, so it's not a solution.

Is there anybody with the same issue and perhaps a good (lazy) solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

French should appear in the other localizations list if your main language to English. Unfortunately, you can't change it after the fact :-(

Anyway, make sure that you don't have the same problem *inside* your app as well, i.e. the Localization native development region (CFBundleDevelopmentRegion) in your info.plist should be English, too.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't find where to switch my main language on uTunes Connect. Is it tied to my account params ? Where can I change this ? Rgd.

Comment: Oops, it seems that you still can't change that.